# Meteor easy-search nested fields in users collection

Tags: mongodb, meteor, selector

I have nested properties in my users collection such as: "users.cast.eyes"

How can I search over those using easy-search selector facets?

```
/*This is not working, because "eyes" is a nested property*/
if (options.search.props.eyes) {
  selector.eyes = options.search.props.eyes;
}

/*This is not working, I'm getting a not such property error*/
if (options.search.props.eyes) {
  selector.cast.eyes = options.search.props.eyes;
}
```

I appreciate any help, thanks

Comment: With MongoDB, you can query on nested files of your document using dot notation, take a look at [this part of the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/#query-on-nested-field)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You answered it yourself already. Use a String based property to query nested objects:

```js
selector['cast.eyes'] = ...
```